# SSRS One to Many Join/Lookup DataSet

Tags: join, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, lookup

In SSRS I am trying to create a table or matrix using two datasets that have a one-to-many relationship. The table/matrix needs to be tied to the one relationship and join to the many.

I initially tried to do a lookup function, but that is a one-to-one relationship and just returned one value. I'm looking to return all values and each one on a separate row. Here is an example of two datasets, I want to join on the CustomerID column and return the CountriesOfBusiness column. Is there a different function in SSRS that will do this?

[image: Dataset1 - This is what is]

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you tried Lookupset function built into SSRS?

Comment: Yes, but i don't know if i was using it correctly because i couldn't get it to work

Comment: please show us what you did with the lookupset function .. the code

Comment: Instead of using two dataset why don't you write SQL query which will return you records what you needed?

Answer (score 1):

Try this expression in table/matrix: (set Dataset name to be: DataSet1)

=Join(LookupSet(Fields!CustomerID.Value, Fields!CustomerID.Value, Fields!Countries.Value, "DataSet2"), VbCrlf)